# Display data in hierarchical order using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table `department` with the following columns.

```
Id  (P.K.)
Name
ParentDepartmentId (F.K. of same Department table)
```

Now I want to display all the data in hierarchical order using LINQ. something like this:

```
 IT
    .Net
        Web Developer
        Windows Developer
    Java
    PHP
Technical Support
    OffLine
    Online
```

Where IT has 3 sub dept .Net, Java, PHP. again .net has its own sub dept web developer and windows developer and so on.

How I can achieve this using LINQ. I am using ASP.Net MVC 3.0 using C#, Entity Framework etc.

Comment: Do you want to bind it to some treeview?

Comment: Are you looking to display it in like a tree structure.

Comment: I think treeview is a ASP.Net control and I am using asp.net MVC. That's why I want to display it without binding with any control.

Comment: @Cold Told Yes, I want to display it in like a tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the link what exactly I wanted.

http://tpeczek.com/2010/01/asynchronous-treeview-in-aspnet-mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GroupBy` function.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. But how can we use GroupBy in Linq. Can you please give me the query to display it in like a tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link. It uses an extension Method `.AsHierarchy()` to represent Hierarchical data

http://www.scip.be/index.php?Page=ArticlesNET18#AsHierarchy.

The returned object would be in tree structure. You just then have to decided on your presentation logic(space for each child node)

Answer (score 0):

You can build a simple set of Html in your action code assign specific values of your HTML that you build dynamically in your Action with values you get by using linq. Then on you view when you return it using viewdata render it as pure html and use jquery to create the tree here some good example of jquery tree plugin

http://mbraak.github.com/jqTree/